# The FAA P/CG is now PDF only, what do we do with all the broken links?

Tags: discussion

It appears that the FAA, in its **infinite wisdom**, has removed the HTML version of the P/CG (pilot/controller glossary) and all the links that I and others have used are now dead. Example: http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/pcg/F.HTM

As far as I can find out, the P/CG is now only available as a [PDF](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/PCG.pdf). Leaving aside the rights and wrongs of that decision for now, how do we handle all the dead links? Can someone do a mass update to point all existing links at the new URL?

Comment: …What does FAA stand for?

Comment: @voretaq7 I would suggest something, but this is a family website...

Comment: If the html comes back, it might be nice to link to both.

Comment: We could update all of the links to point to [the Internet Wayback Machine](http://archive.org/web/). :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running the following query on [data](http://data.stackexchange.com/aviation/query/297642/posts-which-used-html-version-of-faa-p-cg), I found that only a handful of posts have used this URL (`http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/pcg/`). *Please note that I am **not** including HTML page.*

```
select
  pt.Name as PostType,
  p.CreationDate,
  u.DisplayName as PostWrittenBy,
  p.Body
from Posts p
join PostTypes pt
  on p.PostTypeId = pt.Id
join Users u
  on p.OwnerUserId = u.Id
where p.Body like '%http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/pcg/%'
order by p.CreationDate asc
```

Since there are not many references of it, this task can be done manually by editing each post. *But I am up for other suggestions.*

Comment: Nice query! I had no idea if there were a lot of links or a few, this is good to know

Comment: The Data Explorer data is a little stale (2 days old), but that's probably most of the affected posts. Manual fixing (-> https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/PCG.pdf )is probably the easiest way to deal with this.

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/aviation/query/297700/posts-which-used-html-version-of-faa-p-cg-w-links <-- Updated version of query which generates (usually-working) links. Should work for Questions & Answers. Definitely broken for tag wikis.

Comment: @voretaq7 Thanks! I updated them all manually

Comment: @voretaq7: You can just use `SELECT Posts.Id as [Post Link] ...` and get [magic links](http://data.stackexchange.com/help#magic-columns) automatically. But it looks like all the posts have been fixed already, anyway.